# Replacing the fan of the unnamed graphics card on an HP e9262f

Tags: graphics-card, fan

A while ago, my graphics card fan stopped spinning. It was time to lubricate it, so I unplugged it to add some oil on the bearings. I accidentally broke the wire and couldn't solder it back (I'm not too good).

I'm trying to find a used (or new) fan like mine but it's a bit hard when you don't know the name of your graphic card. Well, I'm not even sure it has a name. The computer is a HP Pavilion Elite e9262f and the **GPU** is ATI Radeon HD 4650.

When I look at the HD 4650 card on Google images, the fan doesn't look the same as mine (the entire card looks different). My bet is I have an unbranded card by HP, but I'm not sure.

Maybe some other fan could fit on my card, even if it's not from the exact same card?
Please help. I've been using my graphic card without a fan for about 2 months already. The temperature stays between 125 and 130 degrees, which maybe could cause damage in the long term.

Comment: Wouldn't it be cheaper to just buy a new fan? Also, I'm pretty sure the fan is broken now.

Comment: I'd say you don't need to know what time of graphic card you have... Just find a fan with the same dimensions, if possible the same voltage/speed, and be sure to solder it correctly.

Comment: You can still probably go for the new fan route, but since you've mentioned that you've been running it, _fan-less_, for **2** months, with temperatures of > **125** degrees (assuming Celsius), you've been pretty much slowly killing it.

Comment: Just buy a fan which fits, or replace the whole heat sink.